# Creating a dictionary with specific items from a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to create a dictionary using only specific values from a list.  Here is my code so far:

```
my_dict = {1: [1], 2: [1, 2], 3: [1, 3], 4: [1, 3, 4], 5: [1, 3, 4, 5], 6: [1, 3, 4, 5, 6]}

my_list = ([1, 1, 0], [1, 2, 100], [1, 3, 150], [1, 4, 150], [1, 5, 10], [1, 6, 20])

new_list = []
o_d = 0
# making the AON list
new_dict = {}

    for i in my_list:

    if i[0] and i[1] in my_dict:
        new_list.append(my_list[o_d][1])
        new_list.append(my_list[o_d][2])

        for key in my_dict:
            new_dict[key] = my_list[o_d][2]

        o_d += 1

    else:
        o_d += 1

print(o_d)
print(new_list)
print(new_dict)
```

The output that I am getting is:

```
6
new_list [1, 0, 2, 100, 3, 150, 4, 150, 5, 10, 6, 20]
new_dict {1: 20, 2: 20, 3: 20, 4: 20, 5: 20, 6: 20}
```

The problem is that I am adding only the third value of the 6th item in my_list, after o_d has looped through the entire list.  How do I add the third value of each o_d iteration?

Here is my expected ouput:

```
{1: 0, 2: 100, 3: 150, 4: 150, 5: 10, 6: 20}
```

Comment: please post expected output

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, output is up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it!

Here is the code:

```
my_dict = {1: [1], 2: [1, 2], 3: [1, 3], 4: [1, 3, 4], 5: [1, 3, 4, 5], 6: [1, 3, 4, 5, 6]}

my_list = ([1, 1, 0], [1, 2, 100], [1, 3, 150], [1, 4, 150], [1, 5, 10], [1, 6, 20])

new_list = []
o_d = 0
# making the AON list
new_dict = {}

for i in my_list:

    new_dict[o_d + 1] = my_list[o_d][2]

    if i[0] and i[1] in my_dict:
        new_list.append(my_list[o_d][1])
        new_list.append(my_list[o_d][2])

        o_d += 1



print(o_d)
print ("new_list", new_list)
print("new_dict", new_dict)
```

And here is the output:

```
6
new_list [1, 0, 2, 100, 3, 150, 4, 150, 5, 10, 6, 20]
new_dict {1: 0, 2: 100, 3: 150, 4: 150, 5: 10, 6: 20}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you rewrite ALL elements of new_dict on each iteration of outter for loop. You need to get rid of inner for loop and rewrite only proper new_dict value or use .append(my_list[o_d][2]) instead depending on what you trying to get in output.

Also, do you aware that "if i[0] and i[1] in my_dict:" checks if i[0] is not null object (e.g. 0, [], {}, etc.) and i[1] in my_dict, not that i[0] and i[1] are both in my_dict? And you can move "o_d += 1" part out of if-else statement as soon as you run it in both if and else anyway.